# Python 2 DataFrame KeyError: u'\x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

The code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

#...

print df.columns
print df[u'总资产']
```

The output:

```
Index([u'余额', u'参考市值', u'可用', u'总资产', u'盈亏', u'资产(资金股份)'], dtype='object')

Traceback (most recent call last): "user_code.py", line 36, in handle_data
    print df[u'总资产']   File "/home/server/y/envs/kuanke/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1797, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)   File "/home/server/y/envs/kuanke/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1804, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)   File "/home/server/y/envs/kuanke/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1084, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)   File "/home/server/y/envs/kuanke/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2851, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)   File "/home/server/y/envs/kuanke/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1572, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)   File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 686, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12280) File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12231)

KeyError: u'\xe6\x80\xbb\xe8\xb5\x84\xe4\xba\xa7'
```

---

Another version works fine.

```
#...

print df.columns
print df[unicode('总资产')]
```

---- Update ---------------------------------------

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[u'总资产'])
print df.columns
print df[u'总资产']
return
```

Output is garbled

> 2016-04-05 09:30:00 - INFO - Index([u'æ»èµäº§'], dtype='object')
>   2016-04-05 09:30:00 - INFO - Series([], Name: æ»èµäº§, dtype:
>   object)

Comment: As an aside, python 3 has better unicode support and should be used unless there is a specific requirement for 2.x.

Comment: Can you boil this down to a small runnable example?

Comment: Yes, I have to use python 2, that's the limitation.

Comment: @tdelaney Updated, got garbled output. Originally, the df came from a different package.

Comment: It seems that the platform provider made some mistake. The u prefix has some problem.

Comment: can you show the python and pandas version? my Python 2.7.12 and Pandas 0.18.1 is working for your case.

Comment: @Tiny.D Yes, it should works just fine. I'm using an online python environment.　Seems that the provider was doing some wrong thing.

Comment: Somewhere along the line a utf-8 string is read into a unicode object without proper decoding. Do you use the coding mark as the second line in your progarms? `# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-`